# How to detect backtick(`) in text and wrap with code tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to check backtick (`) in text and replace it with `<code>` in javascript.

For example:

```
var text = "Hello `@James P. Pauli`, How r you.";
```

Here it should detect the ` and should be replace with `<code>` tag. Output should be this:

```
Hello <code>@James P. Pauli</code>, How r you.
```

Comment: So much effort could be saved by having a brief look at the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace` and `regex` to do this easily!

```js
var text = "Hello `@James P. Pauli`, How r you.";
text = text.replace(/`(.*)`/, '<code>$1</code>');
console.log(text);
```

Of if you may have multiple occurrences:

```js
var text = "Hello `@James P. Pauli`, How r `you`.";
text = text.replace(/`(.*?)`/g, '<code>$1</code>');
console.log(text);
```

Comment: You saved my day, That is what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.replace`. Also have a look at [regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

```js
var text = "Hello `@James P. Pauli`, How r you.";

text = text.replace(/`((?!`).+)`/g,'<code>$1</code>');

console.log(text);
```